# Creating new table from existing select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a new table into database. My code is below

```
CREATE TABLE Master_data AS
select a.*, COALESCE(b.content_view,0) as content_view, COALESCE(b.headline_view,0) as headline_view
FROM [Britannia_MMx_2021].[dbo].[Sales_20210323] a
left join [Britannia_MMx_2021].[dbo].[Doximity_20220328] b on a.NPI = b.NPI
           and a.Year_Mon = b.Date;
```

I am getting this error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 46
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL?

Comment: how come you error is on line 46, provided SQL has 5 lines

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL snippet displays characteristics of TSQL. In TSQL (e.g. in MS SQL Server) you do **not** use "create table as" followed by a select statement, instead you use an `INTO` clause e.g.

```
SELECT a.*
    , COALESCE(b.content_view, 0) AS content_view
    , COALESCE(b.headline_view, 0) AS headline_view
INTO Master_data
FROM [Britannia_MMx_2021].[dbo].[Sales_20210323] a
LEFT JOIN [Britannia_MMx_2021].[dbo].[Doximity_20220328] b ON a.NPI = b.NPI
    AND a.Year_Mon = b.DATE;
```

In MySQL you do use `CREATE TABLE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] new_table [ AS ]`